# org-mobile-push gives args out of range

Tags: mobileorg

I'm trying to set up org-mobile, but I just get an error whenever I try to push:

```
Creating agendas...
Args out of range: 1, 1
```

I've tried both with a blank config and a config as below. EDIT5: Changing `org-agenda-files` to use `quote` rather than `list` doesn't remove the error message.

```
(setq org-directory "~/org")
(setq org-agenda-files (list "~/org/notes.org"
                            "~/org/todo.org"
                            "~/org/work.org"))

(setq org-mobile-inbox-for-pull "~/org/inbox.org")
(setq org-mobile-directory "~/Dropbox/Apps/MobileOrg")

(setq org-capture-templates
      '(("t" "Todo" entry (file+headline "~/org/todo.org" "Tasks")
        "* TODO %?\n  %i\n  %a")
        ("w" "Work" entry (file+datetree "~/org/work.org")
        "* %?\nEntered on %U\n  %i\n  %a")
        ("n" "Notes" entry (file+datetree "~/org/notes.org")
        "* %?\nEntered on %U\n  %i\n  %a")
        ))
```

I've tried both with empty org files and my filled org files, but I get the same error anyhow.

I have zero elisp skills, so I'm not even sure how I can start debugging this issue or get a stack-trace to see where the bug happens.

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

EDIT: I think I managed to get a backtrace, but this looks like black magic.
EDIT2: I have removed a lot of text that contained special characters with the text STUFF WITH CONTROL CHARACTERS for it to render properly here.

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (args-out-of-range 1 1)
  vertical-motion(37 nil)
  (1+ (vertical-motion (or max (buffer-size)) window))
  (save-restriction (widen) (narrow-to-region (min beg end) (if (and (not count-final-newline) (= 10 (char-before (max beg end)))) (1- (max beg end)) (max beg end))) (goto-char (point-min)) (1+ (vertical-motion (or max (buffer-size)) window)))
  (save-excursion (save-restriction (widen) (narrow-to-region (min beg end) (if (and (not count-final-newline) (= 10 (char-before (max beg end)))) (1- (max beg end)) (max beg end))) (goto-char (point-min)) (1+ (vertical-motion (or max (buffer-size)) window))))
  (if (= beg end) 0 (save-excursion (save-restriction (widen) (narrow-to-region (min beg end) (if (and (not count-final-newline) (= 10 (char-before ...))) (1- (max beg end)) (max beg end))) (goto-char (point-min)) (1+ (vertical-motion (or max (buffer-size)) window)))))
  (let (count-final-newline window) (if (= beg end) 0 (save-excursion (save-restriction (widen) (narrow-to-region (min beg end) (if (and (not count-final-newline) (= 10 ...)) (1- (max beg end)) (max beg end))) (goto-char (point-min)) (1+ (vertical-motion (or max (buffer-size)) window))))))
  vim-empty-lines-count-screen-lines(2760 5382 37)
  (1- (vim-empty-lines-count-screen-lines (window-start) (point-max) screen-height))
  (- screen-height (1- (vim-empty-lines-count-screen-lines (window-start) (point-max) screen-height)))
  (let ((screen-height (- (window-height) 1 (if header-line-format 1 0)))) (- screen-height (1- (vim-empty-lines-count-screen-lines (window-start) (point-max) screen-height))))
  (save-current-buffer (set-buffer (window-buffer)) (let ((screen-height (- (window-height) 1 (if header-line-format 1 0)))) (- screen-height (1- (vim-empty-lines-count-screen-lines (window-start) (point-max) screen-height)))))
  (progn (select-window (car save-selected-window--state) (quote norecord)) (save-current-buffer (set-buffer (window-buffer)) (let ((screen-height (- (window-height) 1 (if header-line-format 1 0)))) (- screen-height (1- (vim-empty-lines-count-screen-lines (window-start) (point-max) screen-height))))))
  (unwind-protect (progn (select-window (car save-selected-window--state) (quote norecord)) (save-current-buffer (set-buffer (window-buffer)) (let ((screen-height (- (window-height) 1 (if header-line-format 1 0)))) (- screen-height (1- (vim-empty-lines-count-screen-lines (window-start) (point-max) screen-height)))))) (internal--after-with-selected-window save-selected-window--state))
  (save-current-buffer (unwind-protect (progn (select-window (car save-selected-window--state) (quote norecord)) (save-current-buffer (set-buffer (window-buffer)) (let ((screen-height (- ... 1 ...))) (- screen-height (1- (vim-empty-lines-count-screen-lines ... ... screen-height)))))) (internal--after-with-selected-window save-selected-window--state)))
  (let ((save-selected-window--state (internal--before-with-selected-window window))) (save-current-buffer (unwind-protect (progn (select-window (car save-selected-window--state) (quote norecord)) (save-current-buffer (set-buffer (window-buffer)) (let ((screen-height ...)) (- screen-height (1- ...))))) (internal--after-with-selected-window save-selected-window--state))))
  (progn (let ((save-selected-window--state (internal--before-with-selected-window window))) (save-current-buffer (unwind-protect (progn (select-window (car save-selected-window--state) (quote norecord)) (save-current-buffer (set-buffer (window-buffer)) (let (...) (- screen-height ...)))) (internal--after-with-selected-window save-selected-window--state)))))
  (unwind-protect (progn (let ((save-selected-window--state (internal--before-with-selected-window window))) (save-current-buffer (unwind-protect (progn (select-window (car save-selected-window--state) (quote norecord)) (save-current-buffer (set-buffer ...) (let ... ...))) (internal--after-with-selected-window save-selected-window--state))))) (internal--after-save-selected-window save-selected-window--state))
  (save-current-buffer (unwind-protect (progn (let ((save-selected-window--state (internal--before-with-selected-window window))) (save-current-buffer (unwind-protect (progn (select-window ... ...) (save-current-buffer ... ...)) (internal--after-with-selected-window save-selected-window--state))))) (internal--after-save-selected-window save-selected-window--state)))
  (let ((save-selected-window--state (internal--before-save-selected-window))) (save-current-buffer (unwind-protect (progn (let ((save-selected-window--state (internal--before-with-selected-window window))) (save-current-buffer (unwind-protect (progn ... ...) (internal--after-with-selected-window save-selected-window--state))))) (internal--after-save-selected-window save-selected-window--state))))
  vim-empty-lines-nlines-after-buffer-end-aux(#<window 3 on *Backtrace*>)
  (if (and window-start (or (and (window-end) (= (point-max) (window-end))) (not (pos-visible-in-window-p (point-max) window)))) 0 (vim-empty-lines-nlines-after-buffer-end-aux window))
  (save-current-buffer (set-buffer (window-buffer window)) (if (and window-start (or (and (window-end) (= (point-max) (window-end))) (not (pos-visible-in-window-p (point-max) window)))) 0 (vim-empty-lines-nlines-after-buffer-end-aux window)))
  vim-empty-lines-nlines-after-buffer-end(#<window 3 on *Backtrace*> nil)
  (apply (quote max) (vim-empty-lines-nlines-after-buffer-end w window-start) (mapcar (quote vim-empty-lines-nlines-after-buffer-end) (remq w (get-buffer-window-list nil nil t))))
  (vim-empty-lines-update-overlay-aux (apply (quote max) (vim-empty-lines-nlines-after-buffer-end w window-start) (mapcar (quote vim-empty-lines-nlines-after-buffer-end) (remq w (get-buffer-window-list nil nil t)))))
  (progn (vim-empty-lines-update-overlay-aux (apply (quote max) (vim-empty-lines-nlines-after-buffer-end w window-start) (mapcar (quote vim-empty-lines-nlines-after-buffer-end) (remq w (get-buffer-window-list nil nil t))))) (move-overlay vim-empty-lines-overlay (point-max) (point-max)))
  (if (overlayp vim-empty-lines-overlay) (progn (vim-empty-lines-update-overlay-aux (apply (quote max) (vim-empty-lines-nlines-after-buffer-end w window-start) (mapcar (quote vim-empty-lines-nlines-after-buffer-end) (remq w (get-buffer-window-list nil nil t))))) (move-overlay vim-empty-lines-overlay (point-max) (point-max))))
  (let ((w (or window (let ((w (selected-window))) (and (window-valid-p w) w))))) (if (overlayp vim-empty-lines-overlay) (progn (vim-empty-lines-update-overlay-aux (apply (quote max) (vim-empty-lines-nlines-after-buffer-end w window-start) (mapcar (quote vim-empty-lines-nlines-after-buffer-end) (remq w (get-buffer-window-list nil nil t))))) (move-overlay vim-empty-lines-overlay (point-max) (point-max)))))
  vim-empty-lines-update-overlay(#<window 3 on *Backtrace*>)
  (progn (select-window (car save-selected-window--state) (quote norecord)) (vim-empty-lines-update-overlay w))
  (unwind-protect (progn (select-window (car save-selected-window--state) (quote norecord)) (vim-empty-lines-update-overlay w)) (internal--after-with-selected-window save-selected-window--state))
  (save-current-buffer (unwind-protect (progn (select-window (car save-selected-window--state) (quote norecord)) (vim-empty-lines-update-overlay w)) (internal--after-with-selected-window save-selected-window--state)))
  (let ((save-selected-window--state (internal--before-with-selected-window w))) (save-current-buffer (unwind-protect (progn (select-window (car save-selected-window--state) (quote norecord)) (vim-empty-lines-update-overlay w)) (internal--after-with-selected-window save-selected-window--state))))
  (lambda (w) (let ((save-selected-window--state (internal--before-with-selected-window w))) (save-current-buffer (unwind-protect (progn (select-window (car save-selected-window--state) (quote norecord)) (vim-empty-lines-update-overlay w)) (internal--after-with-selected-window save-selected-window--state)))))(#<window 3 on *Backtrace*>)
  mapc((lambda (w) (let ((save-selected-window--state (internal--before-with-selected-window w))) (save-current-buffer (unwind-protect (progn (select-window (car save-selected-window--state) (quote norecord)) (vim-empty-lines-update-overlay w)) (internal--after-with-selected-window save-selected-window--state))))) (#<window 3 on *Backtrace*>))
  (progn (mapc (function (lambda (w) (let ((save-selected-window--state (internal--before-with-selected-window w))) (save-current-buffer (unwind-protect (progn ... ...) (internal--after-with-selected-window save-selected-window--state)))))) (window-list (selected-frame) -1)))
  (unwind-protect (progn (mapc (function (lambda (w) (let ((save-selected-window--state ...)) (save-current-buffer (unwind-protect ... ...))))) (window-list (selected-frame) -1))) (internal--after-save-selected-window save-selected-window--state))
  (save-current-buffer (unwind-protect (progn (mapc (function (lambda (w) (let (...) (save-current-buffer ...)))) (window-list (selected-frame) -1))) (internal--after-save-selected-window save-selected-window--state)))
  (let ((save-selected-window--state (internal--before-save-selected-window))) (save-current-buffer (unwind-protect (progn (mapc (function (lambda (w) (let ... ...))) (window-list (selected-frame) -1))) (internal--after-save-selected-window save-selected-window--state))))
  (progn (select-frame (selected-frame) (quote norecord)) (let ((save-selected-window--state (internal--before-save-selected-window))) (save-current-buffer (unwind-protect (progn (mapc (function (lambda ... ...)) (window-list (selected-frame) -1))) (internal--after-save-selected-window save-selected-window--state)))))
  (unwind-protect (progn (select-frame (selected-frame) (quote norecord)) (let ((save-selected-window--state (internal--before-save-selected-window))) (save-current-buffer (unwind-protect (progn (mapc (function ...) (window-list ... -1))) (internal--after-save-selected-window save-selected-window--state))))) (if (frame-live-p old-frame) (progn (select-frame old-frame (quote norecord)))) (if (buffer-live-p old-buffer) (progn (set-buffer old-buffer))))
  (let ((old-frame (selected-frame)) (old-buffer (current-buffer))) (unwind-protect (progn (select-frame (selected-frame) (quote norecord)) (let ((save-selected-window--state (internal--before-save-selected-window))) (save-current-buffer (unwind-protect (progn (mapc ... ...)) (internal--after-save-selected-window save-selected-window--state))))) (if (frame-live-p old-frame) (progn (select-frame old-frame (quote norecord)))) (if (buffer-live-p old-buffer) (progn (set-buffer old-buffer)))))
  vim-empty-lines-update-overlay-windows()
  #<subr set-window-buffer>(nil #<buffer *SUMO*> nil)
  ad-Advice-set-window-buffer(#<subr set-window-buffer> nil #<buffer *SUMO*>)
  apply(ad-Advice-set-window-buffer #<subr set-window-buffer> (nil #<buffer *SUMO*>))
  set-window-buffer(nil #<buffer *SUMO*>)
  #[(buffer-or-name &optional norecord force-same-window) "STUFF WITH CONTROL CHARACTERS" [buffer-or-name buffer force-same-window norecord entry switch-to-buffer-preserve-window-point window-normalize-buffer-to-switch-to window-buffer window-minibuffer-p user-error "Cannot switch buffers in minibuffer window" pop-to-buffer window-dedicated-p t "Cannot switch buffers in a dedicated window" window-prev-buffers already-displayed get-buffer-window 0 set-window-buffer nil set-window-start selected-window set-window-point 2 select-window displayed] 5 2229158 (list (read-buffer-to-switch "Switch to buffer: ") nil (quote force-same-window))](#<buffer *SUMO*> nil nil)
  ad-Advice-switch-to-buffer(#[(buffer-or-name &optional norecord force-same-window) "STUFF WITH CONTROL CHARACTERS" [buffer-or-name buffer force-same-window norecord entry switch-to-buffer-preserve-window-point window-normalize-buffer-to-switch-to window-buffer window-minibuffer-p user-error "Cannot switch buffers in minibuffer window" pop-to-buffer window-dedicated-p t "Cannot switch buffers in a dedicated window" window-prev-buffers already-displayed get-buffer-window 0 set-window-buffer nil set-window-start selected-window set-window-point 2 select-window displayed] 5 2229158 (list (read-buffer-to-switch "Switch to buffer: ") nil (quote force-same-window))] #<buffer *SUMO*>)
  apply(ad-Advice-switch-to-buffer #[(buffer-or-name &optional norecord force-same-window) "STUFF WITH CONTROL CHARACTERS" [buffer-or-name buffer force-same-window norecord entry switch-to-buffer-preserve-window-point window-normalize-buffer-to-switch-to window-buffer window-minibuffer-p user-error "Cannot switch buffers in minibuffer window" pop-to-buffer window-dedicated-p t "Cannot switch buffers in a dedicated window" window-prev-buffers already-displayed get-buffer-window 0 set-window-buffer nil set-window-start selected-window set-window-point 2 select-window displayed] 5 2229158 (list (read-buffer-to-switch "Switch to buffer: ") nil (quote force-same-window))] #<buffer *SUMO*>)
  switch-to-buffer(#<buffer *SUMO*>)
  helm-switch-to-buffers(#<buffer *SUMO*>)
  helm-execute-selection-action-1()
  helm-execute-selection-action()
  #[0 "STUFF WITH CONTROL CHARACTERS" [(helm-source-buffers-list helm-source-recentf helm-source-buffer-not-found) nil nil nil nil "*helm mini*" nil nil nil nil mapcar #[257 "STUFF WITH CONTROL CHARACTERS" [] 3 "\n\n(fn V)"] funcall make-byte-code 0 "STUFF WITH CONTROL CHARACTERS" vconcat vector [nil helm-log "restore variables"] 5 "\n\n(fn)" helm-initialize helm-display-buffer helm--remap-mouse-mode 1 add-hook post-command-hook helm--maybe-update-keymap helm--update-header-line helm-log "show prompt" #[0 "\300 \207" [helm-cleanup] 1 "\n\n(fn)"] helm-read-pattern-maybe helm-execute-selection-action "[End session] " make-string 41 45 helm-buffer helm-quit helm-in-persistent-action helm-current-source helm-source-name helm-restored-variables helm-prevent-escaping-from-minibuffer] 9 "\n\n(fn)"]()
  funcall(#[0 "STUFF WITH CONTROL CHARACTERS" [(helm-source-buffers-list helm-source-recentf helm-source-buffer-not-found) nil nil nil nil "*helm mini*" nil nil nil nil mapcar #[257 "STUFF WITH CONTROL CHARACTERS" [] 3 "\n\n(fn V)"] funcall make-byte-code 0 "STUFF WITH CONTROL CHARACTERS" vconcat vector [nil helm-log "restore variables"] 5 "\n\n(fn)" helm-initialize helm-display-buffer helm--remap-mouse-mode 1 add-hook post-command-hook helm--maybe-update-keymap helm--update-header-line helm-log "show prompt" #[0 "\300 \207" [helm-cleanup] 1 "\n\n(fn)"] helm-read-pattern-maybe helm-execute-selection-action "[End session] " make-string 41 45 helm-buffer helm-quit helm-in-persistent-action helm-current-source helm-source-name helm-restored-variables helm-prevent-escaping-from-minibuffer] 9 "\n\n(fn)"])
  helm-internal((helm-source-buffers-list helm-source-recentf helm-source-buffer-not-found) nil nil nil nil "*helm mini*" nil nil nil)
  apply(helm-internal ((helm-source-buffers-list helm-source-recentf helm-source-buffer-not-found) nil nil nil nil "*helm mini*" nil nil nil))
  helm((helm-source-buffers-list helm-source-recentf helm-source-buffer-not-found) nil nil nil nil "*helm mini*" nil nil nil)
  apply(helm ((helm-source-buffers-list helm-source-recentf helm-source-buffer-not-found) nil nil nil nil "*helm mini*" nil nil nil))
  helm(:sources (helm-source-buffers-list helm-source-recentf helm-source-buffer-not-found) :buffer "*helm mini*" :ff-transformer-show-only-basename nil :truncate-lines t)
  helm-mini()
  call-interactively(helm-mini nil nil)
  command-execute(helm-mini)
```

EDIT3: I haven't set up email for emacs yet, and I have already opened this issue, so I'm waiting to contact the bug mailing list I found. Might still be useful to add the bug report information here.

```
Emacs  : GNU Emacs 24.5.1 (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.20.6)
 of 2016-06-04 on juergen
Package: Org-mode version 8.3.4 (8.3.4-79-gbd4948-elpaplus @ /home/simendsjo/.emacs.d/elpa/org-plus-contrib-20160606/)

current state:
==============
(setq
 org-id-locations-file "/home/simendsjo/.emacs.d/.cache/.org-id-locations"
 org-tab-first-hook '(org-hide-block-toggle-maybe org-babel-hide-result-toggle-maybe org-babel-header-arg-expand)
 org-clock-persist-file "/home/simendsjo/.emacs.d/.cache/org-clock-save.el"
 org-speed-command-hook '(org-speed-command-default-hook org-babel-speed-command-hook)
 org-occur-hook '(org-first-headline-recenter)
 org-metaup-hook '(org-babel-load-in-session-maybe)
 org-html-format-drawer-function '(lambda (name contents) contents)
 org-log-done 'time
 org-latex-format-inlinetask-function 'org-latex-format-inlinetask-default-function
 org-confirm-shell-link-function 'yes-or-no-p
 org-ascii-format-inlinetask-function 'org-ascii-format-inlinetask-default
 org-link-translation-function 'toc-org-unhrefify
 org-present-mode-hook '(spacemacs//org-present-start)
 org-agenda-restore-windows-after-quit t
 org-latex-format-headline-function 'org-latex-format-headline-default-function
 org-default-notes-file "notes.org"
 org-startup-indented t
 org-after-todo-state-change-hook '(org-clock-out-if-current)
 org-latex-format-drawer-function '(lambda (name contents) contents)
 org-src-mode-hook '(org-src-babel-configure-edit-buffer org-src-mode-configure-edit-buffer)
 org-agenda-before-write-hook '(org-agenda-add-entry-text)
 org-babel-pre-tangle-hook '(save-buffer)
 org-mode-hook '(#[nil "\300\301\302\303\304$\207" [org-add-hook change-major-mode-hook org-show-block-all append local] 5]
                 #[nil "\300\301\302\303\304$\207" [org-add-hook change-major-mode-hook org-babel-show-result-all append local] 5]
                 org-babel-result-hide-spec org-babel-hide-all-hashes spacemacs/load-yasnippet toc-org-enable org-bullets-mode
                 flyspell-mode spacemacs/add-org-surrounds evil-org-mode org-eldoc-load spacemacs//init-company-org-mode
                 company-mode)
 org-archive-hook '(org-attach-archive-delete-maybe)
 org-ascii-format-drawer-function '(lambda (name contents width) contents)
 org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c-hook '(org-babel-hash-at-point org-babel-execute-safely-maybe)
 org-cycle-hook '(org-cycle-hide-archived-subtrees org-cycle-hide-drawers org-cycle-show-empty-lines
                  org-optimize-window-after-visibility-change)
 org-plantuml-jar-path "/opt/plantuml/plantuml.jar"
 org-present-mode-quit-hook '(spacemacs//org-present-end)
 org-export-async-init-file "/home/simendsjo/.emacs.d/layers/org/org-async-init.el"
 org-babel-tangle-lang-exts '(("haskell" . "hs") ("emacs-lisp" . "el") ("elisp" . "el"))
 org-confirm-elisp-link-function 'yes-or-no-p
 org-startup-with-inline-images t
 org-metadown-hook '(org-babel-pop-to-session-maybe)
 org-html-format-headline-function 'org-html-format-headline-default-function
 org-mobile-directory "~/Dropbox/Apps/MobileOrg"
 org-babel-load-languages '((emacs-lisp) (plantuml . t) (sql . t) (haskell . t) (sh . t))
 org-html-format-inlinetask-function 'org-html-format-inlinetask-default-function
 org-fontify-whole-heading-line t
 org-agenda-files '("~/org/notes.org" "~/org/todo.org" "~/org/work.org")
 org-clock-out-hook '(org-clock-remove-empty-clock-drawer)
 org-confirm-babel-evaluate 'simendsjo/org-confirm-babel-evaluate
 org-mobile-inbox-for-pull "~/org/inbox.org"
 )
```

EDIT4: Looking at the org-mobile.el, the error seems to be within this block:

```
(message "Creating agendas...")
(let ((inhibit-redisplay t)
(org-agenda-files (mapcar 'car org-mobile-files-alist)))
  (org-mobile-create-sumo-agenda))
(message "Creating agendas...done")
```

I don't become any smarter though :/

EDIT6: Could it be something strange with this variable?

```
org-mobile-files-alist is a variable defined in `org-mobile.el'.
Its value is (("~/org/notes.org" . "notes.org")
("~/org/todo.org" . "todo.org")
("~/org/work.org" . "work.org"))
```

EDIT7: I notice it creates the buffer `*SUMO*` containing my agendas:

```
Week-agenda (W23):
Monday      6 June 2016 W23
Tuesday     7 June 2016
Wednesday   8 June 2016
Thursday    9 June 2016
Friday     10 June 2016
    todo:       Scheduled:  DONE some task here
Saturday   11 June 2016
    todo:       In   6 d.:  TODO some task :tag1:tag2:
Sunday     12 June 2016

=======================================================================================================================================
Global list of TODO items of type: ALL
    notes:      TODO task
    todo:       TODO other task
    todo:       TODO ... more tasks

=======================================================================================================================================
Week-agenda (W23):
more agenda views
```

EDIT8: With some tedious printf debugging I found the failing line. I still have no idea why it fails.

```
(defun org-store-agenda-views (&rest parameters)
  "Store agenda views."
  (interactive)
  ; This line below is the one that fails
  (eval (list 'org-batch-store-agenda-views)))
```

The documentation for the function

```
org-batch-store-agenda-views is an autoloaded Lisp macro in `org-agenda.el'.

(org-batch-store-agenda-views &rest PARAMETERS)

Run all custom agenda commands that have a file argument.
```

EDIT9: I've further reduced it. It's a bit difficult for me to go deeper as I don't even know how I can print information about variables correctly. Look at the comment in the following code block

```
;;;###autoload
(defmacro org-batch-store-agenda-views (&rest parameters)
  "Run all custom agenda commands that have a file argument."
  (let ((cmds (org-agenda-normalize-custom-commands org-agenda-custom-commands))
  (pop-up-frames nil)
  (dir default-directory)
  (pars (org-make-parameter-alist parameters))
  cmd thiscmdkey thiscmdcmd match files opts cmd-or-set bufname)
    (save-window-excursion
      (while cmds
  (setq cmd (pop cmds)
        thiscmdkey (car cmd)
        thiscmdcmd (cdr cmd)
        match (nth 2 thiscmdcmd)
        bufname (if org-agenda-sticky
        (or (and (stringp match)
          (format "*Org Agenda(%s:%s)*" thiscmdkey match))
            (format "*Org Agenda(%s)*" thiscmdkey))
      org-agenda-buffer-name)
        cmd-or-set (nth 2 cmd)
        opts (nth (if (listp cmd-or-set) 3 4) cmd)
        files (nth (if (listp cmd-or-set) 4 5) cmd))
  (if (stringp files) (setq files (list files)))
  (when files
    (message "BUG: The next statement crashes with '1+: Args out of range: 1, 1'")
    ; It seems it's the following thing that crashes within the eval call
    ; (org-agenda nil thiscmdkey)
    (org-eval-in-environment (append org-agenda-exporter-settings
            opts pars)
      (org-agenda nil thiscmdkey))
    ; We never get here
    (set-buffer bufname)
    (while files
      (org-eval-in-environment (append org-agenda-exporter-settings
              opts pars)
        (org-agenda-write (expand-file-name (pop files) dir) nil t bufname)))
    (and (get-buffer bufname)
        (kill-buffer bufname)))))))
```

Answer (score 2):

I "found" the bug. The problem was the `vim-empty-lines` package.